# Out-sample error for disjoint input spaces

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-statistics

I am trying to understand the fundamentals of Bayesian machine learning and I found an interesting task, which I have tried to solve:

We are in the setting of a binary classification problem with $Y=\{-1,+1\}$ and an input space $X=\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{n} X_i$, where all $X_i$ are disjoint sets. Further, we are given a hypothesis $h$ from some hypothesis space. The probability that $h$ classifies an instance $x$ **incorrectly**, given that $x$ belongs to $X_i$, is $p^{n-i}$. The probability of $x$ belonging to $X_i$ is $\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$ for all $0\leq i\leq n$ and $0<p<1$.

So in short we have $p(h(x)\text{ incorrect}|x\in X_i)=p^{n-i}$ and $p(x\in X_i)=\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$.

The first task wants me to find $p(x\in X_i|h(x)\text{ incorrect})$, which can be found by using Bayes theorem. The result is $p(x\in X_i|h(x)\text{ incorrect})=\frac{1}{p(h)}\cdot \binom{n}{i}p^n(1-p)^{n-i}\varpropto \binom{n}{i}p^n(1-p)^{n-i}$.

In a second step I am supposed to find $E_{out}(h)$ using the $0/1-error$. Using the defintion of $E_{out}(h)$, I am getting to the point

$E_{out}(h)=\int\limits_{X}(\sum\limits_{y\in Y}e(y,h(x))\cdot p(x,y))dx=\int\limits_{X}(\sum\limits_{y\in Y}e(y,h(x))\cdot p(y|x)\cdot p(x))dx$

However, at this point I am struggling to find the next step. I would be very grateful if someone can explain me, how the next step could look like to find the overall solution.

Edit:

After thinking about the task more and more, I got the idea to use the fact that we are using the $0/1-error$. The sum can be simplified to $p(y'|x)p(x)$, where $y'\neq h(x)$, since in this case, we make an error, i.e. $e(y,h(x))=1$. Using this, we get

$E_{out}(h)=\int\limits_{X}p(y'|x)\cdot p(x))dx$

However, I still don't really see the connection between the probabilities in the integral and the given probabilities from the task. I mean $p(x)$ and $p(x\in X_i)$ are different probabilities...

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this task? Can you credit the original source where you saw it? What does it mean to talk about the probability that $h$ classifies correctly when $h$ is given?    What is the probability taken over?

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for your comment. I found this task in an old ML exam. Unfortunately, I will not be able to share the link (I don't know if I am allowed to), but the task is exactly as I posted it. Therefore, I am not able to give you more information about the task, so all information should be given (at least I hope so).